# C# Dictionary (Order Keys) versus Java SortedMap lexicographic order

Tags: java, c#

I am using a SortedMap in Java and attempting to order a C# Dictionary by Keys. Comparing the outputs I would expect to see the same orders, however the orderings are different and I'm not sure why.

```java
SortedMap<String, String> orderedByKey = new TreeMap<>();
orderedByKey.put("0:10", "");
orderedByKey.put("10:12+", "");
orderedByKey.put("2:10", "");
orderedByKey.put("1:10", "");
orderedByKey.put("10:1", "");
```

```
Dictionary<string, string> tmp = new Dictionary<string, string>();
tmp.Add("0:10", "");
tmp.Add("10:12+", "");
tmp.Add("2:10", "");
tmp.Add("1:10", "");
tmp.Add("10:1", "");
var orderedByKey = tmp.OrderBy(y => y.Key).ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Value);
```

Java orders them as follows...

0:10
10:1
10:12+
1:10
2:10

C#

0:10
1:10
10:1
10:12+
2:10

The line I was thinking down here was that my C# ordering had ordered the Dictionary but using a different precedent to Java i.e. C# considers ':' before '0' and in Java '0' is before ':'.

Comment: Why are you expecting any particular order from the dictionary returned by `ToDictionary`? The order of the items in a `Dictionary` is **undefined**. Doesn't matter in what order you *add* the items, the result still has *undefined* order. Say so right there in the **documentation** of the [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) class.

Comment: I agree with @Andreas here. In .NET, the order in which elements of a dictionary appear when enumerating the dictionary (or its Keys or Values collections) is undefined. It would be a bad idea to rely on an incidental behavior that the documentation specifically tells you not to rely on and that might perhaps change when you switch to a different .NET version or target platform (.NET Framework, .NET Core, Mono, etc...)...

Comment: @RufusL Hi Rufus. My objective is to be able to out put Key-Value pairs in the same order (by Key) in both Java and C#. I don't mind what type of Dictionary, Maps etc I use or if they are ordered at insertion time or after all items inserted. Just as long as when I output the Key-Value pairs (e.g. to a text file for diffing) they are guaranteed to be in the same order.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for pointing this out, this explains why relying on Dictionary ordering is a bad idea. I have also tried with a SortedDictionary (which I understand will enumerate in order by key) and I see exactly the same ordering returned i.e. SortedMap in Java is different order to SortedDictionary in C#.

Comment: The ordering is not based on the container you're using, but on the `string` type itself (and it's default `String.Compare(string, string)` method). You have to specify that you want an `Ordinal` comparison if you want it to behave like Java. See my answer below for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that in C#, [`String.CompareTo`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,141ddf57a009d676) takes culture into account by default, which provides a slightly different result than Java's [`String.compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) method, which uses pure lexicographical comparison.

If you want the C# string comparison to behave like Java, then we can simply specify `StringComparer.Ordinal` as the comparison type, which compares just the ordinal position of each character:

```
private static void Main()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> tmp = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"0:10", ""},
        {"10:12+", ""},
        {"2:10", ""},
        {"1:10", ""},
        {"10:1", ""}
    };

    var javaSorted = tmp.OrderBy(item => item.Key, StringComparer.Ordinal)
        .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Value);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", javaSorted.Select(item => item.Key)));

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: If you instead want Java to behave like C#, you use a [`Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) with the `TreeMap`, e.g. `new TreeMap<>(Collator.getInstance())`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for [`SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) which represents a collection of key/value pairs that are sorted on the key.

Comment: Does that really produce a different sorting result? (I was looking at *" the orderings are different and I'm not sure why"*)

Comment: The OP is getting a new , sorted dictionary with `var orderedByKey = tmp.OrderBy(y => y.Key).ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Value);`

Comment: @StvnBrkdll I believe OP is asking for a similar data structure for which he don't have to order by explicitly

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I tried this and I see same behaviour. I expected SortedDictionary in C# to order by same precedence as SortedMap in Java but I see...

Java = 0:10, 10:1, 10:12+, 1:10, 2:10
C# = 0:10, 1:10, 10:1, 10:12+, 2:10